# Error trying to display decoded JSON results in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am attempting to display data pulled from the Ticketmaster discovery API. I am new to using API and would appreciate some help in getting this working.

```
struct EventImport : View{
    
    @State var events: [Event] = []
//error: Cannot convert value of type '[EventImport.Event]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
    
    var body: some View {
        List(events) { event in
            HStack{
                let dealLink1 = event.url
                Text("\(event.name)")
                Button()
                {
                    openLink1(linking: dealLink1)
                }label: {
                    Image(systemName: "link.circle")
                }
                .tint(.teal)
                .bold()
            }
        }
        .task {
            do {
                if let results = try await fetchTMEvents() {
                    events = results
                }
            } catch {
                print("---> error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func fetchTMEvents() async throws -> [Event]? {
        let apiKey = "XXXXXXXXX"
        let tmStart = Date()
        let tmEnd = Date()+(3600*24)
        let tmCity = 303
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        let formattedStart: String = dateFormatter.string(from: tmStart)
        let formattedEnd: String = dateFormatter.string(from: tmEnd)
        let urlTM = URL(string: "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?dmaId=303&apikey=\(apiKey)&dmaId=\(tmCity)&startDateTime=\(formattedStart)&endDateTime=\(formattedEnd)")!
        
        let(data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: urlTM)
        print("API")
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as Any)
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
        return decoded.embedded.events
    }
    
    func openLink1(linking: String){
        guard let url = URL(string: linking) else {
            return
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }

    struct Welcome: Codable {
        let links: WelcomeLinks
        let embedded: WelcomeEmbedded
        let page: Page

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case links = "_links"
            case embedded = "_embedded"
            case page
        }
    }

    struct WelcomeEmbedded: Codable {
        let events: [Event]?
    }

    struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
        var name, type, id: String
        let test: Bool
        var url: String
        let locale: String
        let images: [Image]
        let sales: Sales
        let dates: Dates
        let classifications: [Classification]
        let promoter: Promoter
        let links: EventLinks
        let embedded: EventEmbedded

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name, type, id, test, url, locale, images, sales, dates, classifications, promoter
            case links = "_links"
            case embedded = "_embedded"
        }
    }

    struct Classification: Codable {
        let primary: Bool
        let segment, genre, subGenre: Genre
    }

    struct Genre: Codable {
        let id, name: String
    }

    struct Dates: Codable {
        let start: Start
        let timezone: String
        let status: Status
    }

    struct Start: Codable {
        let localDate: String
        let dateTBD, dateTBA, timeTBA, noSpecificTime: Bool
    }

    struct Status: Codable {
        let code: String
    }

    struct EventEmbedded: Codable {
        let venues: [Venue]
        let attractions: [Attraction]
    }

    struct Attraction: Codable {
        let name, type, id: String
        let test: Bool
        let locale: String
        let images: [Image]
        let classifications: [Classification]
        let links: AttractionLinks

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name, type, id, test, locale, images, classifications
            case links = "_links"
        }
    }

    struct Image: Codable {
        let ratio: Ratio
        let url: String
        let width, height: Int
        let fallback: Bool
    }

    enum Ratio: String, Codable {
        case the16_9 = "16_9"
        case the3_2 = "3_2"
        case the4_3 = "4_3"
    }

    struct AttractionLinks: Codable {
        let linksSelf: SelfElement

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case linksSelf = "self"
        }
    }

    struct SelfElement: Codable {
        let href: String
    }

    struct Venue: Codable {
        let name, type, id: String
        let test: Bool
        let locale, postalCode, timezone: String
        let city: City
        let state1: State1
        let country: Country
        let address: Address
        let location: Location
        let markets: [Promoter]
        let links: AttractionLinks

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name, type, id, test, locale, postalCode, timezone, city, state1, country, address, location, markets
            case links = "_links"
        }
    }

    struct Address: Codable {
        let line1: String
    }

    struct City: Codable {
        let name: String
    }

    struct Country: Codable {
        let name, countryCode: String
    }

    struct Location: Codable {
        let longitude, latitude: String
    }

    struct Promoter: Codable {
        let id: String
    }

    struct State1: Codable {
        let name, stateCode: String
    }

    struct EventLinks: Codable {
        let linksSelf: SelfElement
        let attractions, venues: [SelfElement]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case linksSelf = "self"
            case attractions, venues
        }
    }

    struct Sales: Codable {
        let salesPublic: Public

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case salesPublic = "public"
        }
    }

    struct Public: Codable {
        let startDateTime: Date
        let startTBD: Bool
        let endDateTime: Date
    }

    struct WelcomeLinks: Codable {
        let linksSelf, next: Next

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case linksSelf = "self"
            case next
        }
    }

    struct Next: Codable {
        let href: String
        let templated: Bool
    }

    struct Page: Codable {
        let size, totalElements, totalPages, number: Int
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some context and describe what the issue is with your code.

Comment: I am getting the error that is commented in the first few lines on code @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a local type called Image:

```
struct Image: Codable {
    let ratio: Ratio
    let url: String
    let width, height: Int
    let fallback: Bool
}
```

This makes your call to `Image(systemName: "link.circle")` invalid. When SwiftUI is given badly typed values, it often does not provide a useful error message.

The smallest fix to this would be to be specific in `body`:

```
SwiftUI.Image(systemName: "link.circle")
```

I would recommend renaming the local Image type, however, since it's likely to create more confusion later. I would also recommend moving most of this code out of the View. Putting all this model logic and business logic (`fetchTMEvents`) into the View has made it very overly complicated and difficult to test independently.